# Programmatically scrape Facebook meta tags

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making a "generate your ___ name" generator and am having trouble with the facebook share portion.

Basically the user fills out a form then gets results. My first idea was to have the results in an iframe which would have a unique URL because of the GET parameters, which generated the correct facebook share info. The problem with that was the link shared would go directly to the "results" iframe.

I decided instead to keep it all on one page, and submit the form via POST, reload the page and show the results. If there is no POST data, it shows the default page. My problem now is re-scraping the Facebook data in order to share the correct "generated" image. (Programmatically, not at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). I found the script below which is supposed to do that, but haven't had any luck.

Does anybody know of an alternative way of doing this that would show the correct "generated" image in facebook but also link back to the original page so that others can then generate their own name?

This is an example here that does it, but I haven't been able to reverse-engineer what they are doing: http://www.zimbio.com/generator/d_rN-Gyttd2/What's+Your+'Game+of+Thrones'+Warrior+Name

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE URL"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="FB APP ID" />

<script>
$.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com',
    {
        id: 'URL HERE',
        scrape: true
    },
    function(response){
       console.log(response);
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Facebook fetches these with a specific user agent (something like `facebookexternalhit`).

Comment: You need to create a unique url that Facebook can scrape that have the right information on it

Comment: The other commenters are right, you need a unique URL that Facebook can scrape. However you might also be interested to know that it's possible to get Facebook to re-scrape a page programatically: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-update

Comment: Thanks guys, so it looks like I'm back to using GET parameters to make a unique URL. Assuming that this URL with the parameters will be shared to facebook, any ideas on how to show the original (and not results) page to people who click on it in FB?

Comment: I'm thinking I'll just use a PHP session...I'll post to record how it went!